# What is the " result object " from stripe.redirectToCheckout?

Tags: javascript, json, api, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

```
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51JaZneFymkOlJfbtifS7RjJeFPZTchtlvU5iiVmemkU76vOFWWPZOW9GwBDb9518RCoOfkvUQkGV92TyEMaXqYgh00eb6kLKZj');
     var session = "<?php echo $checkout_session['id']; ?>";
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session })
                  .then(function(result) {
          // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using `error.message`.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```

For some reason i cant get access to " result "  value in >> .then(function(result) <<
can anyone tell me whats values are available  " result " ?

Comment: The [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout) doesn't state anything more than this. Not sure why you can't stick a breakpoint on `if (result.error)` to investigate. I'm guessing that the page is redirected upon success.

Answer (score 0):

While this is unlikely in most scenarios, you'd get back the `result` with an `error` and `message` as [described](https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout).

You can test this using for example Chrome's network throttling to simulate a network failure.